# Can appuim able to connect and locate elements when the device is in use say call?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

Can appuim able to connect and locate element when the device is in use say call?
I am automating a Scenario of Call Merge but not able to click on Element, post device gets engaged in a call.